# Microsoft Excel getting seconds elapsed in a time interval

Tags: excel, converters

Is there a formula in excel to get the total seconds elapsed in a specific time period? For example I need to get the total seconds starting 12:00mn to 6:37am. I also have more than 2000 rows, so having the exact formula that can compute all at once would make it easier. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it, the simplest one is to simply multiply the time difference by 86400 (24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds).

```
 =(EndTime-StartTime)*86400
```

Comment: Hi! The formula worked but it shows "#VALUE!" instead of the result so I have to re-type the time one by one. Is there a way to fix it? Thanks

Comment: It's got probably something to do with the number format of your data - use Paste Special and multiply by 1 all input cells.  Alternatively do it in the formula:

     =(EndTime*1-StartTime*1)*86400

Comment: It still doesn't work. I also tried the formula: =EndTime * 86400 but it also shows #VALUE!